# Apollo GraphQL "not found in type: 'query_root'"

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

I'm using the Apollo iOS SDK and receive this error:

```
...not found in type: 'query_root'
```

I'm new to GraphQL and Apollo. What does this error mean exactly? I can get the same query to work in Postman.

Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the relevant code and the full error. If that error is coming from the server, which is what it sounds like, then your query is likely not the same as the query that's working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was the result of a typo in the URL for the API in my code. There are 2 places where the URL is required (for iOS Apollo):

1) Build Phases

2) Creating the HTTPNetworkTransport required to initialize the ApolloClient

The second item had the typo.